# Add new column and new value

Tags: r, data.table, strsplit

I have a table called "new" and I wanted to extract year from ManufactureDate to a new column "year".

new$ManufactureDate:

```
2014-01-01 
2016-01-01
2005-01-01
1997-11-01
```

Create a new column and "new" will look like this:

```
ManufactureDate    year
2014-01-01         2014
2016-01-01         2016
2005-01-01         2005
1997-11-01         1997
```

My code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(new)){
  new["year"] <- NA
  new$year[i] <- strsplit(new$ManufactureDate, "-")[[i]][1]
  print(new$year[i])
}
```

Result:
It printed out successfully, but when I checked table "new", it shows like this, not sure what happened:

```
ManufactureDate    year
2014-01-01         NA
2016-01-01         NA
2005-01-01         NA
1997-11-01         1997
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually going to vote against even creating the year column. If you are using an actual date column, then you should extract the year from that already existing column, rather than denormalizing your data and creating a dummy year column.

```
df <- data.frame(ManufactureDate=as.Date(c("2014-01-01", "2016-01-01",
                                           "2005-01-01", "1997-11-01")))
format(df$ManufactureDate, "%Y")
[1] "2014" "2016" "2005" "1997"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is actually pretty easy for me to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a `for` loop. Along with what you've tried so far (using `strsplit`), here is one possibility:

```
new$year <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(new$ManufactureDate), "-"), "[[", 1);
#  ManufactureDate year
#1      2014-01-01 2014
#2      2016-01-01 2016
#3      2005-01-01 2005
#4      1997-11-01 1997
```

---

### Sample data

```
new <- read.table(text =
    "ManufactureDate
    2014-01-01
2016-01-01
2005-01-01
1997-11-01", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well! I just haven't learned how to use sapply yet.

Comment: No worries @Lara19; familiarising yourself with `sapply`/`lapply` (and the whole `*apply` family) will definitely be time well spent for future R coding.